# Software pattern for matching object with handles

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I have been thinking in an approach for this problem but I have not found any solution which convince me. I am programming a crawler and I have a downloading task for every url from a urls list. In addition, the different html documents are parsed in different mode depending of the site url and the information that I want to take. So my problem is how to link every task with its appropriate parse.

The ideas are:

1. Creating an huge 'if' where check the download type and to associate a parse. 
   (Avoided, because the 'if' is growing with every new different site added to crawler)
2. Using polymorphism, to create a download task different for every different site and related to type of information which I want to get, and then use a post-action where link its parse.
   (Increase the complexity again with every new parser)

So I am looking for some kind of software pattern or idea for say:

- Hey I am a download task with this information
- Really? Then you need this parse for extract it. Here is the parse you need.

Additional information:

The architecture is very simple. A list with urls which are seeds for the crawler. A producer which download the pages. Other list with html documents downloaded. And a consumer who will should apply the right parse for the page.

Depending of the page download sometimes we need use a parse A, or a parse B, etc..

**EDIT**

An example:

We have three site webs: site1.com, site2.com and site3.com

There are three urls type which we want parsing: site1.com/A, site1.com/B, site1.com/C, site2.com/A, site2.com/B, site2.com/C, ... site3.com/C

Every url it parsed different and usually the same information is between site1.com/A - site2.com/A - site3.com/A ; ... ; site1.com/C - site2.com/C - site3.com/C

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [Genetic Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm#Methodology) aproached solution fits for your description of the problem, what you need to find first is the basics (atomic) solutions.

Here's a tiny description from wikipedia:

In a genetic algorithm, a population of candidate solutions (called individuals, creatures, or phenotypes) to an optimization problem is evolved toward better solutions. Each candidate solution has a set of properties (its chromosomes or genotype) which can be mutated and altered; traditionally, solutions are represented in binary as strings of 0s and 1s, but other encodings are also possible.[2]

The evolution usually starts from a population of randomly generated individuals, and is an iterative process, with the population in each iteration called a generation. In each generation, the fitness of every individual in the population is evaluated; the fitness is usually the value of the objective function in the optimization problem being solved. The more fit individuals are stochastically selected from the current population, and each individual's genome is modified (recombined and possibly randomly mutated) to form a new generation. The new generation of candidate solutions is then used in the next iteration of the algorithm. Commonly, the algorithm terminates when either a maximum number of generations has been produced, or a satisfactory fitness level has been reached for the population.

A typical genetic algorithm requires:

a genetic representation of the solution domain,
a fitness function to evaluate the solution domain.
A standard representation of each candidate solution is as an array of bits.[2] Arrays of other types and structures can be used in essentially the same way. The main property that makes these genetic representations convenient is that their parts are easily aligned due to their fixed size, which facilitates simple crossover operations. Variable length representations may also be used, but crossover implementation is more complex in this case. Tree-like representations are explored in genetic programming and graph-form representations are explored in evolutionary programming; a mix of both linear chromosomes and trees is explored in gene expression programming.

Once the genetic representation and the fitness function are defined, a GA proceeds to initialize a population of solutions and then to improve it through repetitive application of the mutation, crossover, inversion and selection operators.

Comment: I like the idea of a Genetic Algorithm because it involves to improve with every iteration. However I can't set a function to evaluate the solution domain because I don't know what will be the result of a site "well-parsed". For example in site1.com I have a list with 10 items and in site2.com a list with the same information but with 12 items. And the items amount could changing with the time. Hence I can't set at the beginning what should be the right number for the solution.

Comment: @Franb That's why I said: "what you need to find first is the basics solutions...", in this case one would be processItem(item).

Answer (score 0):

I would externalize the parsing pattern / structure in some form ( like XML ) and use them dynamically.

For example, I have to download site1.com an site2.com . Both are having two different layout . I will create two xml which holds the layout pattern .

And one master xml which can hold which url should use which xml .

While startup load this master xml and use it as dictionary. When you have to download , download the page and find the xml from dictionary and pass the dictionary and stream to the parser ( single generic parser) which can read the stream based on Xml flow and xml information.

In this way, we can create common patterns in xml and use it to read similar sites. Use Regular expressions in xml patterns to cover most of sites in single xml.

If the layout is completely different , just create one xml and modify master xml that's it.

The secret / success of this design is how you create such generic xmls and it is purely depends on what you need and what you are doing after parsing.

Comment: Generic xmls are fine but in some cases the layout of site1.com and site2.com are completely different although they have the same information. So it is very difficult create a generic xmls from that, and if in the future you add a new kind of site for parsing you have troubles for adapting these generic xmls to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a connectivity problem. I'd suggest considering the quick find algorithm.

See here for more details.
http://jaysonlagare.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/union-find-algorithms.html

and here's a simple java sample,
https://gist.github.com/gtkesh/3604922